# redirect_to new_user_session_path Not Showing Flash Message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

No matter what I do, I can't get the flash message that I explicitly pass to show:

Controller:

```
flash[:notice] = "Your account was deactivated."
  redirect_to new_user_session_path
```

View:

```
<%- flash.each do |name, msg| -%>
        <%= content_tag :div, msg, :id => "flash_#{name}" if msg.is_a?(String) %>
      <%- end -%>
```

This is located on the devise /users/sign_in page, which I have customized. I have tried every iteration I could think of. flash.now, including the notice inline with the redirect_to, trying to force it to use the default YML file, trying to force it to show using something other than flash... nothing.

Comment: Does the page have any javascript console errors? Is it possible that the HTML is rendering, but your client-side javascript or maybe your CSS is hiding the elements?

Comment: It seems you are using devise gem here,if so,when working with devise you can only edit the devise view templates by first adding this to `devise.rb` file `config.scoped_views = true`,ensure you have added this first.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work. No JavaScript errors

Answer (score 1):

The devise_error_messages works for me.

Try to take out the flash  and add this instead

Check out this link https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, devise does that. When you want to show a flash message from devise controller, you have to use the method they provide for that - [set_flash_message!](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/DeviseController:set_flash_message)

In your case that would be

```
set_flash_message! :notice, :deactivation_notice
redirect_to new_user_session_path
```

And then you need to add deactivation notice to i18n, as they rely on it.

Or, as an alternative, you can add your notice to the proper i18n path, and devise will add it automatically.